# Como hacer un layout circular o un Circular ViewPager en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Lo que busco hacer es como la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Son como items seleccionables, quiero hacer tal cual a la imagen, las opciones giran de izquierda a derecha o de derecha a izquierda, las imagenes se agrandan, cuando vas a la siguiente opcion y la que se va al costado se va achicando.

Comment: Prueba de implementarlo con esa librería https://github.com/antonyt/InfiniteViewPager

Comment: Podria servirme. gracias.

Comment: También puede que te sirva: https://github.com/geftimov/android-viewpager-transformers Ya que permite definir distintas transiciones entre los elementos del viewpager

Answer (score 1):

Hice algo similar con una librería llamada *CircularImageView*, en mi caso usé imágenes, ya que tú no detallas muy bien las opciones, si usas *"texto o imágenes"*, te dejo la librería y adáptala según lo requieras:

https://github.com/lopspower/CircularImageView